# Using named colors with Cairo graphics

Tags: cairo, pycairo

I am using pycairo to generate an postscript file. It is a simple file consisting of black lines on a white background. My customer has asked me:

*will it be possible to change the black stroke line to a named color “CutContour”*

Is this possible?

Thanks,

--eric